# Postgresql - Using CASE and PARTITION BY clause to create effective and thrudates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL. I have been working with SQL Server, so I have limited experience with PostgreSQL. I'm trying to convert some SQL Server queries for PostgreSQL and ran into the following issue.

Suppose I have the following table

| key | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2000-01-01 | 1 |
| A | 2001-01-01 | 2 |
| A | 2002-01-01 | 3 |
| B | 2001-01-01 | 4 |
| B | 2002-01-01 | 5 |
| B | 2003-01-01 | 6 |

For each row I want to create two additional columns - `effective_date` and `thru_date`. `effective_date` is the same as `date` and `thru_date` needs to be the next date minus 1 day for the same key. If next date doesn't exit, '2200-01-01' is used for end of time. So the resultant table will look like this

| key | date | value | effective_date | thru_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2000-01-01 | 1 | 2000-01-01 | 2000-12-31 |
| A | 2001-01-01 | 2 | 2001-01-01 | 2001-12-31 |
| A | 2002-01-01 | 3 | 2002-01-01 | 2200-01-01 |
| B | 2000-01-01 | 4 | 2000-01-01 | 2000-12-31 |
| B | 2001-01-01 | 5 | 2001-01-01 | 2001-12-31 |
| B | 2002-01-01 | 6 | 2002-01-01 | 2200-01-01 |

The following query works fine in SQL Server, but runs into syntax error with PostgreSQL.

> Error executing SELECT statement. ERROR: syntax error at end of input

Is there a difference in using `OVER` and `PARTITION BY` clauses for PostgreSQL? Looking at the documentation and other examples, I don't see a difference in using the `LEAD` clause but that seems to be the problem in this query.

```
select a.key, a.date as effdate,
    case
    when LEAD(a.date) OVER (PARTITION BY a.key ORDER BY a.date) is null then '2200-01-01'::date
    else a.date + '-1 day'::interval OVER (PARTITION BY a.key ORDER BY a.date))
    end as thrudate
from table a;
```

Comment: No point tagging SQL Server as you need PostgreSQL experts.

Comment: I assume you have read the PostgreSQL documentation to discovered the differences? And what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I would just use a simple case statement, based on the query you've shown. I don't see a reason to lead or partition by, even with SQL SERVER.

Comment: `If next date doesn't exit, '2200-01-01' is used for end of time. ` <<-- hint: use 'Infinity' for this kind of sentinel. And you don't need the CASE WHEN, there is COALESCE()

Comment: @DaleK the `::date` is a cast in postgres

Comment: @DaleK it's adding to the date, and the result is still a date (or datetime/timestamp). It's like `DATEADD()` in TSQL

Comment: @wildplasser Got your point on using 'Infinity'. However, the date '2200-01-01' is used for a specific reason as a downstream process uses pandas where the max date it can process is '2262-04-11'

Comment: @DaleK I updated the question with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this instead:

```
select a.key, a.date as effdate,
    LEAD(a.date,1, '2200-01-02') OVER (PARTITION BY a.key ORDER BY a.date)
     - interval '1 day' as thrudate
from table a;
```

Comment: I get the logic but it runs into this error `ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "a"`

Comment: @kyc12 it can’t be from that query or you might forgot to alias your table to ‘a’

Comment: Ok, I'm using pycharm to connect to the postgresql db and the GUI tool is throwing that error. Otherwise the query runs ok.